How to manually change the order of appearance of a custom taxonomy on a Wordpress post?
I have a custom taxonomy for authors for each post, it's basically a bank of publications and resources. I've used "get_the_terms" to display them and it's working perfectly! However I can't work out how to manually change the order they appear. I know you can do an array of "order" by its ASC, DESC, ID etc and don't display in the particular order we need it to.
For example say we have John, Sally and Amanda - I'd like to make Sally go first as she is the main author of the post and then John, then Amanda. The author orders will change with each post so it's easier if I can manually order them in the backend and display as they were input on the frontend.
See below how I registered the taxonomy - am I missing something? The sidebar input automatically changes it to alphabetical.
Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks so much.
function wporg_register_taxonomy_authors() {
    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x('Authors', 'taxonomy general name'),
        'singular_name' => _x('Author', 'taxonomy singular name'),
        'search_items' => __('Search Authors'),
        'all_items' => __('All Authors'),
        'parent_item' => __('Parent Authors'),
        'parent_item_colon' => __('Parent Author:'),
        'edit_item' => __('Edit Author'),
        'update_item' => __('Update Author'),
        'add_new_item' => __('Add New Author'),
        'new_item_name' => __('New Author Name'),
        'menu_name' => __('Authors'),
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'public' => true,
        'show_in_rest' => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        // 'hierarchical' => true,
        'rewrite' => ['slug' => 'author'],
    );
    register_taxonomy('authors', ['post'], $args);
}
add_action('init', 'wporg_register_taxonomy_authors');

And this is how I'm displaying them on the front end.
<? $terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'authors');
foreach ($terms as $term) {
    echo '<p class="author">' . __($term->name) . '<span>,</span></p>';
}
?>


What would be the method to sort by? It would seem as though you need some kind of custom field for setting the order in the first place. no?

I think it's automatically alphabetical? I've tried all the other sort bys/orders but to no avail - not sure where to start for a custom order!

You could use the WP_Term_Query to query terms in a specific order.
$terms_query = new WP_Term_Query(array(
    'taxonomy' => 'authors',
    'orderby'  => 'slug__in',
    'slug'     => array(
        'sally',
        'john',
        'amanda
    )
));

